# How to find data of wma at the open position?

Tags: charts, pine-script, trading, indicator, pine-script-v4

I have this plot:

```
WMA_point = wma(close, 9)

plot(WMA_point, title='WMA', color=#000000)
```

It makes a line on the chart. When the price goes up, the line moves up, and vice versa, when the price goes down, it moves down.

I know that it depends on the "close" data.

I would like to find the price data of this wma when (close == open)

EDIT:

I mean: I want to get the first data of the close line wma(close, 9), when the new candle appears, when the (close == open) . I dont need the data of the open line wma(open, 9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use WMA_point[1], which is generally where the price value of the current bar will open at. If you want to take into consideration gapping, you'll need to calculate the wma using n-1 historical close values and with the nth value the current bar's open.

```
//@version=5
indicator("wma open", overlay = true)

len = input.int(10)
     
float wtd_close_sum = 0.0
int denom = 0

for i = 1 to len - 1
    wt = len - i
    wtd_close_sum += close[i] * wt
    denom += wt

wtd_close_sum += open * len
denom += len

wma_open = wtd_close_sum / denom

plot(wma_open)
```

as a function :

```
f_wma_open(_open, _close, _len) =>
    float _wtd_close_sum = 0.0
    int _denom = 0

    for i = 1 to _len - 1
        _wt = _len - i
        _wtd_close_sum += _close[i] * _wt
        _denom += _wt

    _wtd_close_sum += _open * _len
    _denom += _len

    _wma_open = _wtd_close_sum / _denom
    _wma_open
```

Comment: It's not correct. When I check bars on the chart, I find only the bar where close==open to see if it has the same value with the original wma line, but there is still a difference between 2 points: wma(close,9) and wma_open

Comment: There was a small mistake, it's been corrected now

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's still not showing the correct value

Comment: It looks fine to me https://www.tradingview.com/x/ou8h94eu/

Comment: I set a plotshape to check when (close==open) and (WMA_point==wma_open) and I check on many charts with many timeframes but I dont see it.

Comment: and those conditions will almost never occur. There will only ever be a very brief instant when a new bar opens when WMA_point == wma_open, after that the close value used to calculate WMA_point will change to something different and it will no longer be equal.

Comment: But at the bars that have close==open, the WMA_point should have the same value as it was at the first moment, is it correct? "after that the close value used to calculate WMA_point will change to something different" -- I dont understand this, because close value is still the close, what can it change to ?

Comment: I tried the len with the value 9, and it shows the exact and expected value. Thank you very much for your help. You may edit your answer and try again. I will accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243269/discussion-between-candyg80-and-rumpypumpydumpy).

Comment: Hello @rumpypumpydumpy, thank you for helping me finding the 1st value of WMA. Can you please help me to do the same with VWMA ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `open` as your source:

```
WMA_point = wma(open, 9)

plot(WMA_point, title='WMA', color=#000000)
```

Cheers, and best of luck with your trading and coding

Comment: No, I mean, I want to get the data of the close line when close == open . I dont need the data of the open line.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to store the price in a `var` when your condition is `true`.

```
var float p = na
WMA_point = wma(close, 9)

if (open == close)
    p := WMA_point  // This will have the wma value of the last time open == close

plot(WMA_point, title='WMA', color=#000000)
```

Comment: I would like to compare that value with the current wma value. How do I do it? When I open any chart, can I get the difference between WMA_point with the current wma value?