# How to find and display the first value of VWMA when bar open

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

The VWMA is:

```
plot(vwma(close, 14))
```

And that VWMA can be same as:

```
the_vwma(_src, _len) =>
    sma(_src * volume, _len) / sma(volume, _len)
plot(the_vwma(close, 14))
```

I am looking for a way to find the first value of VWMA when the new bar comes, means, when it has the first (close==open), and display that value on the chart, so each time I open a new chart, I can see it immediately. Someone tells me to store the value in a var, but that value is not correct when I open a new chart and look at the current bar which is already running. It doesnt have the correct value of the first moment.

I look around and see that someone did a similar thing with the Bollinger Bands [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612000/how-to-find-the-first-value-of-bollinger-bands-when-bar-open) or the WMA [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71581723/how-to-find-data-of-wma-at-the-open-position) - but im unable to make that thing work with VWMA

Please help me to write a similar function for VWMA.

Comment: You question is unclear, please give us more examples and details

Comment: I just need the value of the very first point of the VWMA line, right at the moment of new bar, or maybe easier when close==open. So, every time I open a chart, I can see that point on the chart, even if the current close is not equal the current open.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'open' value, which is the value at the opening of the bar, even if the bar is already opened and still moving.
For example :

```
first_value_of_VWMA = the_vwma( open, 14)
```

Comment: NO, it's not correct. The value changes constantly following the change of close. It should be a fixed value. And im sure that it's not what I need to find, because when I use `barstate.isrealtime and barstate.isnew`, it gives me a very different value, which is the correct one. I have already waited on the chart and stared at the bars to see the value when the new bar came.

Comment: of course. how do you define the ´first’ value of open ? which bar it is ?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear: I need the first value of vwma(close, 14) - and could you please check the link in the question and run the code in the accepted answer to see what I mean

Comment: The accepted answer in your link is just code, no explanation at all. Please explain us what is 'the first' value you need ? Is it the first value on the screen ? the first value of the day ? the first value of the week ?

Comment: The first value of the current bar. Any current bar. Any timeframe. Just open the chart, go to any timeframe, you will always see the line VWMA and its current value. But that value have been changed when the close changes. I need the very first value of the line before it changes. If you run the code from the accepted answer, then go to any timeframe, any chart, you will get the current value of BB, also the very first value of BB before it changes (the value appears when the bar is new, when close==open). I have added the 2nd link in the question to make you understand what I need

Answer (score 0):

If you want the close of the bar previous to the open of the current bar, you need to use close[1].  You should also be aware that close[1] does not always equal open[0], price jumps happen and depending on your timeframe, they can be significant.  To limit calculations to the period just before the close of a bar, you can use:
if barstate.isconfirmed